# How do I connect to mysql database with dbplyr

Tags: mysql, r, dbplyr

I have an employee table in a local mysql database.  I'm trying to use dbplyr and DBI to connect to the database/table and query data into a dataframe.

Heres is my code:

```
library(dbplyr)
library(DBI)
library(RMySQL)
my_db <-  DBI::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL()(), 
                        host = "127.0.0.1",
                        port = 3306,
                        user = "username",
                        password = "password"
  )

employee <- tbl(my_db, "employee")

view(employee)
```

When I run the script, I get the following error:

```
Error in DBI::dbConnect((RMySQL::MySQL())(), host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root",  : 
  attempt to apply non-function
```

I've been googling the error message, but have not been able to find a solution.

I using a mysql 8.0CE database and have been able to connect to it via shiny using the RMySQL library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for `dbConnect` says that the first argument is: `drv` - an object that inherits from DBIDriver, or an existing DBIConnection object (in order to clone an existing connection).

When I connect to MS SQL server I use the command:

```
db_connection = dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = connection_string)
```

Where a connection string is an alternative way of capturing host, port, etc.

The `RMySQL` documentation gives the following example:

```
con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname = "test")
```

So this issue is probably the extra pair of brackets:

```
# current code causing error
my_db <-  DBI::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL()(), 
# try this instead
my_db <-  DBI::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
```